# get accounts's transactions details in solidity

Tags: solidity, transactions

I want get transactions of a account and get the details of it(such as time and etc.) in solidity.
How can i do this? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to access past transactions in Solidity. If you're only interested in the users interactions with that contract, then you can keep track of a users transactions in a map/array.